# Get IP Ping results Asynchronously c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, ip, ping

I have a situation where i have a list of IP addresses. I want to start a ping process at once with all of them and that should be async.

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
{
   Ping pingSender = new Ping();
  var tasks = theListOfIPs.Select(ip => pingSender.SendPingAsyn(ip,2000));
   var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

   return results.ToList();
}
```

According to my understanding this operation will wait till all ping results are returned. What i want to do is whenever a single result is completed i want to utilize that result. so i.e as soon as one ping returns result i want to store that immediately without waiting for other pings to complete.

How can i do that ?

Comment: You can use Task.WaitAny and loop until all tasks are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i want to do is whenever a single result is completed i want to utilize that result.

I think the cleanest solution is to define a "ping and process" operation:

```
private async Task<PingReply> PingAndProcessAsync(Ping pingSender, string ip)
{
  var result = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, 2000);
  ProcessPingResult(result);
  return result;
}
```

Then run multiple of these concurrently:

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
{
  Ping pingSender = new Ping();
  var tasks = theListOfIPs.Select(ip => PingAndProcessAsync(pingSender, ip));
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  return results.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Usage example? Seems to exit and continue before all tasks actually complete.

Comment: @Tsukasa: Yes. Because it's asynchronous.

Comment: best way to tell when all tasks have been completed or would there need to be a different approach.

Comment: @Tsukasa: You'd use `await`, like this: `await PingAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of WaitAny in this case

```
  var results = await Task.WaitAny (tasks);
```

---

Below version is loger but i think this might help you..

```
bool onetaskCompleted= false;
private readonly Object obj = new Object();

private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
{
   Ping pingSender = new Ping();
   var tasks = theListOfIPs.Select(ip => pingSender.SendPingAsyn(ip,2000));
   List<Task> continuetask = new List<Task>();
   foreach(Task t in taks)
   {
     continuetask.Add(t.ContinueWith(Action));
   }

   var results = await Task.WhenAll(continuetask);

   return results.ToList();
}

private void ContinuationAction()
{
     lock(obj)
     {
       if(!onetaskCompleted) 
          onetaskCompleted = true;
     }
     if(!onetaskCompleted)
     {
       //execute code 
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will try this out. I want to code it that way so it responds me in most quickest time possible as i want to add markers to map based on these results. If i use WaitAny will it fire any event as and when ping returns returns.

Comment: @SachinTrivedi - that is reason i suggest you try for second solution because that will allows you to does continuation ...dont forget to mark it as accepted/upvote if works for you

Comment: Thanks. I am getting error here continuetask.Add(t.ContinueWith(Action)); What should be replacement for "Action" ?

Comment: @SachinTrivedi - action replaced by method ...you can check msdn you will get you answer here ContinueWith((t)=> ContinuationAction())

Comment: Sorry but i am not clear how will i get ping result in ContinuationAction ? Can you please post full working code. as var results = await Task.WhenAll(continuetask); returns compilation error.